# How to have a 3rd component be displayed on the same page user click on a button inside of a component (using router-outlet)?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-routerlink

I have an accounts page that has a list of accounts. When the user clicks on one of the accounts a new component displays right next to it showing the account's recent transactions. This is done with a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` that is set dynamically by having the routerlink set dynamically with a function and in the html like

```
<a href="" [routerLink]="accountLink(account)">
```

But now I need a similar functionality on that dynamically displayed component so when a button clicked to show the Tx details there is a 3rd panel that shows another component template with the details of that specific transaction.

I've been trying to set auxiliary routes and child routes and things for the last few hours but with no luck.

For clarity, here is the accounts page with the 2 components currently showing:
[image]

As you can see the "TEST" part is where I want to show the transaction details when the user clicks on the (i) button in the transactions list in the middle.

Here is the transaction details component I want displayed in that 3rd part.
[image]